# Workbook_BeforeClose not executing after using VBA editor

Tags: excel, event-handling, vba

As the title suggests, I am having a problem with Excel's Workbook_BeforeClose event handler.  I know I am using the correct method signature (shown below) because it has worked in the past, and I have correctly placed the event handler in the "ThisWorkbook" module of the VBA editor.  However, I have noticed that whenever I do a significant amount of coding within the VBE (in other modules), this method is not executed.  Even when I place breakpoints inside, the breakpoints are not hit before the workbook closes.  Again, this only happens if I have been messing around with other modules in the VBE; if I just open the workbook and immediately close it, this method runs fine and the breakpoints get hit.  Saving or not saving the workbook does not seem to make a difference, and this problem occurs in Excel 2013 and 2016 (haven't tried opening the workbook in earlier versions).  This issue is really starting to impede my workflow, so if anyone has a thought on why my Workbook_BeforeClose handler is not being called, I would very much appreciate the help!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'More code...
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [posting this question](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/936754-workbook-beforeclose-not-calling-after-opening-visual-basic-applications-editor.html#post4499872) on the Mr. Excel forum, I was given the solution:  Some of the other modules that I was editing contained optimization code. This included disabling Application events while the macro was running, then turning them back on after completion. However, while debugging, I would obviously occasionally stop the macro before it completed, so Application events were never being turned back on!

So now, all I have to do is execute "Application.EnableEvents = True" in the Immediate Window before I try to close the workbook, and my event handler runs fine!